# How to prove a non-monotone function is non-negative in some given interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Consider the function $f(x, n) = -\left(2n+3\right) x^{n}+\left(2n+1\right)x^{\left(n+1\right)}+4\left(n+1\right)x^{\left(2n\right)}-\left(4n+1\right)x^{\left(2n+1\right)}+1, x\in (0, 1), n=1, 2,\cdots$.

We'd like to prove $f(x, n)$ is non-negative $\forall x \in (0, 1), n=1, 2, \cdots$.

---

Something I tried.
We can plot the function in the interval and find it's positive and non-monotone.
[image]

But since it is difficult to determine the root where the derivative is 0, I have no idea how to prove it is always positive in the interval $(0, 1)$ for and $n=1, 2, \cdots$.

---

I tried to compute the partial derivative about $n$, but the partial derivative is not always positive or negative. Here is the graph for the partial derivative.

[image]

Is there any way to prove the nonnegativity?

Comment: What does "prove" mean to you? You've plotted it, and it's nonnegative. What sort of analysis are you looking for?

Comment: I just plot one case $n=1$ and I can try many cases but not for all $n=1, 2, \cdots$. I want to find some way to show it is positive for all $n$ and $x\in (0, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will reedit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.